# How do I write a script that compares folder/symbolic-link names from two diffrent folders?

Tags: ubuntu, automation, shell-scripting, symbolic-link

I need help in writing a script to create symbolic links. Here is a script that I have been running on background.

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/home/$USER/www"
DEST="/var/www"
while true; do
    find $SOURCE -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "old.**" -exec ln -s -- {} "$DEST"/{} \;
    find $DEST -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec test ! -e {} \; -delete
sleep 30
done
```

Now I would like this script to perform couple more tasks.

- Ignore already linked folders and <strike>folders with 'old.' prefix</strike>.
- <strike>Remove symbolic-link from $DEST if the main folder is not available
  in $SOURCE.</strike>

Please help me to add those functionality on this script. Thanks.

Comment: What did your attempts look like? Possibly those will just need minor modifications to achieve what you want.

Comment: My attempt is to compare 'find $DEST -maxdepth 1 -type l' with 'find $SOURCE -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name "old.*"' and check if there are new folders in $SOURCE or links without main folders. Then create/remove links. The thing is I am not able to put it together here.

Comment: @ErikE I wonder if you could help me with this?

Comment: I believe this should not be too difficult and fun at the same time, however I'm holiday-stuck on iThings mostly. I would like to test before posting, so I'll likely post an answer eventually if it hasn't been solved :-)

Comment: Now it almost works as I wanted but only thing is it tries to create links of all of those folders other than old.* in $SOURCE. :|

Comment: Well done! I'm thinking it should be within reach to create a test to see if a symlink is present and resolves. I tried googling using those keywords and it seems others have done this succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be more cumbersome than you expected, but I would rewrite the `-exec ...` part as a separate script that gets one input parameter (the directory name to symlink to), and then checks if the symlink already exists (e.g. `if [ -h "$DEST/$1" ] ...`) and, if necessary, whether it resolves to a correct location (e.g. `if [ $(readlink $DEST/$1) == $SOURCE/$1 ] ...`. If both conditions are true, we skip the file, otherwise the symlink is (re)created.

Then you call this script in the exec clase like this:
 `find $SOURCE -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "old.**" -exec make-symlink.sh {} \;`

A couple of further points:

- The file names that `find` will substitute in place of `{}` *will include `$SOURCE`*: e.g. in your case the final `exec` command will look like this: `ln -s -- /home/user/www/public /var/www/home/user/www/public`. Solve this problem by using `basename`.
- on some systems (OS X) the $SRC directory itself will be included in the list of directories `find` finds. This is probably not what you want. Solve this problem by removing first line of `find` output or by adding `-not -name $(basename $SOURCE)` clause.

Hope this helps.